# Can't determine even function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, functions, functional-calculus

Given $f(x)= \cos\left(\log( x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right))$

As to check if even or not, we usually use 
$f(-x)=f(x)$

But here if we do that the  even nor odd 
However when graph is plotted we get even. 
How do we determine such function as even without plotting graphs...

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "But here if we do that the even nor odd "?

Comment: I think the OP means: if we do that here ('that' referring to checking if $f(x)=f(-x)$), then we find that its not even nor odd.

Comment: @5xum Meaning the function changes when substituted with (-x) as input so it can't be even nor odd

Comment: @safeerkhan can you show how you proved that the function changes?

Comment: @5xum That is what I'm not sure of actually but when we put -x then the x variable inside log function changes like    cos(log(-x+(√(1+x))) so doesn't the log function change?

Comment: Parenthesis missing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed an even function; you should plug $-x$ again. You might also investigate the relationship between $(-x + \sqrt{1 + x^2)}$ and $(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2})$ (Hint: What happens when you multiply them? What does that say about their logarithms?) Finally, just note that cosine is even function. (I cannot comment right now, so if someone wants to move this to comments, be my guest)

Answer (score 0):

As the cosine is an even function, its argument has to be an even or an odd function.

Then the argument of the logarithm must be either an even function, or one such that $$f(-x)=\frac1{f(x)}.$$

Taking $x=1$, we see that $-1+\sqrt2\ne1+\sqrt2$ and evenness is rejected. Now, as

$$\left(-x+\sqrt{1+(-x)^2}\right)\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)=1+x^2-x^2,$$ the argument of the logarithm indeed has this "inverse" property.

To summarize,

$$f(-x)=\frac1{f(x)},\\\log(-f(x))=-\log(f(x)),\\\cos(\log(f(-x))=\cos(\log(f(x)).$$